# filter array of objects and display grouped table data javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, object

I wanted to display the table as follows. So I created the following component as shown below named `envTableComponent`. This component loops through the `envResponse` and displays the project name and build.

[image: Image 1]

```
export const envTableComponent = () => {
    let envTable = [];
    const headerTable = ['PROJECT NAME', 'BUILD']
    
    const envResponse = [
        {
          "environment": "PROJECT 1",
          "verticals": [
            {
              "projects": [
                {
                  "name": "ITALY",
                  "runs": [
                    {
                      "build": "B2345",
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "environment": "PROJECT 2",
          "verticals": [
            {
              "projects": [
                {
                  "name": "FRANCE",
                  "runs": [
                    {
                      "build": "A4322",
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "MOSCOW",
                    "runs": [
                      {
                        "build": "C3456",
                      }
                    ]
                  }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
      ],

    const projects = [];
        envResponse.forEach((envMetric) => {
        envMetric.verticals.forEach((vertical) => {
            vertical.projects.forEach((project) => {
            const obj = {};
            obj.projectName = project.name;
            obj.build = project.runs[0].build;
            projects.push(obj);
            });
        });
        });
        envTable = projects

    return (
        <>
        <div>ENVIRONMENT</div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    {headerTable && headerTable.map
                    ((header, indx) => {
                        return (<th key={indx}>{header}</th>)
                    })}
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {envTable && envTable.length > 0 && envTable.map
                ((row, indx) => {
                    return (<tr key={indx}>
                    <td>{row.projectName}</td>
                    <td>{row.build}</td>
                    </tr>)
                })}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </>
    )
}
```

Now, i am trying to do a group by `environment` and then display the projects for each environment. i am expecting my final result to be something like this shown in image below.

Can someone please let me know what changes i have to do in order to show the group by table form for my data.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually quite close: all you need is to actually create a dictionary where you have key-value pairs where the key is the environment and the value is simply the array of projects associated with that environment. If we slightly repurpose your `forEach` logic to use `Array.prototype.reduce`, we can get the structure you want:

```
const projectsByEnv = envResponse.reduce((acc, envMetric) => {
  const { environment, verticals } = envMetric;
  const projects = verticals.flatMap((vertical) => {
    return vertical.projects.map((project) => {
      return {
        projectName: project.name,
        build: project.runs[0].build
      };
    });
  });

  if (acc[environment]) {
    acc[environment].push(...projects);
  } else {
    acc[environment] = projects;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
```

The `projectsByEnv` will simply have the following format: `{PROJECT 1: Array(1), PROJECT 2: Array(2)}`. To output it in your template, we need to step through the object using `Object.entries()`, and use the colspan trick to ensure the environment spans two columns:

```
<tbody>
  {Object.entries(projectsByEnv).map(([environment, projects]) => {
    return (
      <>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">{environment}</td>
        </tr>
        {projects.map((project) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{project.projectName}</td>
              <td>{project.build}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </>
    );
  })}
</tbody>
```

With a bit of a CSS trick as well:

```
td[colspan] {
  border-top: 1px dashed black;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}
```

This is how it looks like after making the above changes:

[image]

You can see the full proof-of-concept example on CodeSandbox:

[image: Edit epic-glade-f36go]